# Get the index of the ul in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, carousel

I have a carousel with different lists. And i have a button next. When i click on the button, the carousel move 200 pixels to left. Than you can see the other images. But i have a problem with this custom made carousel.

I put the script on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwdMP/2/

I would like to get the .index of the carousel. But the carousel is not working with .index. Who can help me, to fix this carousel? Thank you help guys!

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add width en height to the container - wrapper
    var ul = $('.list-thumbnails');
    var lengthUL = $('.list-thumbnails').length + 1;
    var containerWidth = $(ul).outerWidth() * lengthUL;

    $('.container-list-thumbnails').css({
        width: containerWidth
    });


    // Buttons for next and previous
    $('.container-thumbnails').append('<div class="buttons"><a href="#" title="Ga naar de vorige" class="previous">Vorige</a><a href="#" title="Ga naar de volgende" class="next">Volgende</a></div>')
    var buttonPrevious = $('.container-thumbnails .previous');
    var buttonNext = $('.container-thumbnails .next');

    buttonNext.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.ignoreButtons) {
            return;
        }

        var section = $('.container-list-thumbnails');
        var sectionIndex = section.index();

        var x = -300 * (sectionIndex + 1);

        console.log(x);

        this.ignoreButtons = true;

        $('.container-list-thumbnails').animate({
            left: x,
        }, function() {
            this.ignoreButtons = false;
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
});
​
```

Comment: where is previous button click code?

Comment: The previous code. I not make that. I make first the next button code. But the next button is not working good. I need help with this :-)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this question. Why next button doesn't work, what do you expect when you click next. Please elaborate index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your slider to use one click handler for both buttons and to store `sectionIndex` in the parent element `buttons` using jQuery `data('sectionIndex')`. You will need to refine it a bit more so it can't go below zero or beyond the length of thumb lists

```
$('.buttons').data('sectionIndex', 0);
var section = $('.container-list-thumbnails');
$('.buttons a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isNext = $(this).is('.next');
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    //if (this.ignoreButtons) {
        //return;
    //}
    var currIndex = $parent.data('sectionIndex');

    var sectionIndex = isNext ? currIndex + 1 : currIndex - 1;

    $parent.data('sectionIndex', sectionIndex);

    var x = -300 * sectionIndex;

    console.log(x);

    // this.ignoreButtons = true;
    $('.container-list-thumbnails').animate({
        left: x,
    }, function() {
        this.ignoreButtons = false;
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kwdMP/3/

Comment: Thanks for helping!! It works now. :-) Verry happy now! But i have one last question. Is there a way, that i can check. What is the last index. When you are on the last index. Than the next button must be non clickable.

Comment: compare sectionIndex to the length of your lists, or if it is less than zero. I would add class `disabled` to buttons and can check `if( $(this).hasClass('disabled')) return`. Or hide/show buttons

Comment: Can you give e example in the jsfiddle? Thanks!

Comment: example just needs you to check zero condition but hides `next` if at end http://jsfiddle.net/kwdMP/5/ Not perfect yet, but should give you something to work with